# PyDEA package not found

Tags: python

I have installed pydea package but jupyter notebook is throwing Module Not Found Error: No module named 'pydea' error

I am starting out with DEA so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How did you install it? Using the [basic method](https://github.com/jzuccollo/pyDEA/blob/master/README.md#basic) or the [pip method](https://github.com/jzuccollo/pyDEA/blob/master/README.md#pip)?

Comment: Hi. I installed using pip method. I found out that the package was missing a class file and hence throwing an error. The problem is solved now but thanks for answering.